# Как включить функцию пересылки с кнопками в Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет. Если переслать из моего бота сообщение другому человеку, то инлайн кнопки не будут пересылаться. В то же время в других похожих ботах если переслать так же сообщение человеку, то оно пересылается вместе с кнопками. Как можно разрешить пересылку с кнопками в боте?

Comment: Как вы пересылаете?

Comment: вам никто не запрещал отправлять кнопки с сообщением.